# PHP - Failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: php, json, file-get-contents

I am using the `file_get_contents()`. It works on on my local machine, but does not work on my production server. Any help would be appreciated!

Code:

```
$id = ph5740142354e5e
$url = 'http://it.pornhub.com/webmasters/is_video_active?id=' . $id;
$pagina = file_get_contents($url);
```

Comment: I recommend using cURL over file_get_contents()

Comment: Will you share what happens in local environment?

Comment: Are there any errors reported in the logs?

Answer (score 0):

Work with cURL.. I have user this code:

```
function get_data($uri) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    $timeout = 5;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $uri);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}

$pagina = get_data($url)
```